# How to execute a function stored in a dictionary with the interaction of a user in Python?

Tags: python, function

I code a small personal project. Is it possible to call a function with input from a user? Let me explain. If for example the user marks "help", I would like the "cmdHelp ()" function to run. I would like to use a dictionary to be able to do this more cleanly, and store my functions.

```
def userInput():
    RUN = 1
    while(RUN != 0):
        USER = input('↪ ').lower()
        if USER in cmd:
            #execute the function

def helpCmd():
    print('THIS IS THE HELP MENU AHAHAHA !')

def connexion():
    print("› SSH\n› FTP\n")

cmd = {
   'help': helpCmd,
   'connexion': connexion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the way to go: (Note that code print an error message in case of a wrong input)

```
def userInput():
    RUN = 1
    while(RUN != 0):
        cmd_key = input('↪ ').lower()
        func = cmd_lookup.get(cmd_key)
        if func is not None:
            func()
        else:
            print(f'{cmd_key} is invliad func name. Available names are: {[c for c in cmd_lookup.keys()]}')



def helpCmd():
    print('THIS IS THE HELP MENU AHAHAHA !')

def connexion():
    print("› SSH\n› FTP\n")

cmd_lookup = {
   'help': helpCmd,
   'connexion': connexion
}

userInput()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine, just access the `dict` and call the returned function:

```py
def userInput():
    RUN = 1
    while(RUN != 0):
        USER = input('↪ ').lower()
        if USER in cmd:
            cmd[USER]()
```

To be clear, there are two steps here:

```
func = cmd[USER]  # Access cmd to find the function
func()            # now call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to the question, some edits to fit [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) rules:

1: use `run` instead of `RUN`, so with `user` not `USER`.

2: use `while run` instead of `while (run != 0)`.

3: name your function `user_input` instead of `userInput` and so as `help_cmd`.

4: if you never change `cmd` dynamically, i.e you don't modify it - add/remove items from it, then you better name it `CMD`. objects which are "constants" can be named with capital letters.

Comment: I just modified that. thank you for helping me